# trouble hiding scrollbar on div overlay vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I am aware that this question has been asked and answered several times.  however, none of the answers given have worked for me 100%

I have a large video gallery that launches a fullscreen overlay to view the video in, and i need the scrollbar to vanish when the video is playing.

I did find one script that works most of the time, but there are two problems with it.  First, it does not work in microsoft edge, and second, it is the only script I have left that requires jQuery, and i would dearly love to rid my project of this dependency.  here is the script that i have been using.  is there a good vanilla javascript alternative?  thanks in advance

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(function() {
    $(".noscroll").click(function() {
      $(this).next(".hidden").addClass("show");
      $(".noscroll").addClass("blurry");

      var width = $('body').width();

      $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
      var scrollWidth = $('body').width() - width;
      $('body').css('margin-right', scrollWidth + 'px')
    });
    $(".closebtn").click(function() {
      $(".hidden").removeClass("show");
      $(".noscroll").removeClass("blurry");
      $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
      $('body').css('margin-right', '0px')
    })
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(i) {
    var container = $(".hidden");
    if (!container.is(i.target) && container.has(i.target).length === 0) {
      container.removeClass("show");
      $(".noscroll").removeClass("blurry")
    }
    })
  });

  $('.closeVid').click(function() {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto')
  });

  $('.noscroll').click(function() {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden')
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('video').addClass("noscroll")
  })
```

Comment: The script is just a few simple jquery features, you should have no problem rewriting with in vanilla js plus this might be handy https://github.com/oneuijs/You-Dont-Need-jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/konrwcaf/1/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple modal</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .modal {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 9000;
    }
    .modalContent {
      background: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
      min-width: 200px;
      min-height: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: left;
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    body.modalOpen .modal {
      display: block;
    }
    body.modalOpen {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modalContent">
        <p>I'm the modal</p>
        <p><button class="modalCloser">Close modal</button></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p><button class="modalOpener">Open the modal</button></p>

    <p>Content</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.modalCloser');
      for (var i = 0, l = closeButtons.length; i < l; i++) {
        closeButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
          document.body.className = '';
        })
      }
      var openButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.modalOpener');
      for (var i = 0, l = openButtons.length; i < l; i++) {
        openButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
          document.body.className = 'modalOpen';
        })
      }
    })();
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip.  so far, every attempt shuts down my video thumbnails.   not sure if it makes a difference, being as i didn't see bootstrap involved, but it is a div overlay, not a modal.  i built it based on the full screen div overlay example on w3schools.  will keep trying.

Comment: yeah, i went at this for about an hour, converted all the div names to ones used in my project, and although it still worked in its original form, it doesn't work at all in my video gallery.  There are so many things it could be.  its a very complex combination of scripts and css.

Comment: you would think there would be a solution that was almost entirely css.  seems simple.  turn the frikking overflow off when you click a button.  no such luck so far. lol

Comment: It's quite hard to get an idea of what you're trying without an example - could you extract the relevant portions of your project and put it together in a fiddle? Maybe then I could help.